# How can I prevent collapsing the detail row after adding data in Radzen Blazor Data Grid?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, radzen

I am using the Radzen Blazor DataGrid component in my Blazor Server Application. There are two data grids nested (master-detail) for orders and details. When I click an order, order details expand. I click the **add order detail** button and add a new detail to this order. After adding data and clicking **SaveRowDetail**, expanded order details are collapsed.

How can I prevent collapsing the order details after adding a new row in details?

Here is the simplified code:

```
@page "/orderlist"
<PageTitle>Order List</PageTitle>



<h1>Orders</h1>

<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="false" RowClick="RowClick" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_ordersDto" TItem="OrderDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
                ShowExpandColumn="false" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnResize="true" >
<Template Context="order">
<RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    Customer:
    <b>@order?.Customer?.Name</b>
</RadzenCard>
<RadzenTabs>
<Tabs>
<RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
<div id="wrapper">
    <RadzenButton class="rz-background-color-success-light" Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@(() => InsertDetailRow(order.Id))" Disabled="@(_detailToInsert != null)" Size="ButtonSize.Small"/>
   
</div>
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="@(_detailToInsert == null)" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="@(_detailToInsert == null)" Data="@order.OrderDetailsDto"
                TItem="OrderDetailDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true"
                                    AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px" Density="Density.Compact" >
<Columns>

<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Id" Title="Product ID" Frozen="true" OrderIndex="1"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="ProductCode" Title="Product  Code" OrderIndex="2"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="VendorDto.Name" Title="Vendor" Width="200px" OrderIndex="4"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Warehouse" Title="Warehouse" OrderIndex="5"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Currency" Title="Currency" OrderIndex="6"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="OrderId" Title="Order Id" OrderIndex="22"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="PoNotes" Title="PO Notes" OrderIndex="23"/>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200px" OrderIndex="24">
    <Template Context="detail">
        <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>
    </Template>
    <EditTemplate Context="detail">
        <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>
        <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => CancelEditDetail(detail))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>
        <RadzenButton Icon="delete" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => ShowInlineDialog(detail))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
</RadzenTabsItem>

</Tabs>
</RadzenTabs>
</Template>
<Columns>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px"/>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Customer.Name" Title="Customer" Width="200px" Filterable="false"/>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px" Filterable="false"/>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px"/>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenButton Icon="print" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => OpenOrder(order))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
            <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
           
        </Template>
        <EditTemplate Context="order">
            <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
            <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => CancelEdit(order))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
            <RadzenButton Icon="delete" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => ShowInlineDialogOrder(order))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
        </EditTemplate>
    </RadzenDataGridColumn>

</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public string? SelectedStatus { get; set; }

    List<string> warehouse = new();
    IEnumerable<WarehouseAddress?> warehouses;
    
    IList<OrderDto?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Order?> _orders = new List<Order?>();
    IQueryable<OrderDto?> _ordersDto;
    IQueryable<Order?> _order;
    IEnumerable<Vendor?> _vendors;
    IEnumerable<VendorDto?> _vendorsDto;
    IEnumerable<Customer?> _customers;
    IEnumerable<CustomerDto?> _customersDto;   
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDto?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetailDto> _gridDetail;    
    OrderDetail orderDetailMap;
    ClaimsPrincipal user;
    private bool DataLoading = false;

   
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("************ Orders Preparing... ************");
        
        user = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", false);
        }
        if (DataLoading)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DataLoading = true;
            await UpdateOrdersIsCompletedUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
            _vendors = await ViewAllVendorsUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
            _customers = await ViewAllCustomersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
            _order = ViewOrdersUseCase.Execute(user);

            _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order);
             
            _vendorsDto = Mapper.Map(_vendors, _vendorsDto);
            _customersDto = Mapper.Map(_customers, _customersDto);

            warehouses = await ViewAllWarehouseAddressUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
            warehouse = warehouses.Select(w => w.Name).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            DataLoading = false;
        }
        SelectedOrders = new List<OrderDto?> { _ordersDto.FirstOrDefault() };
        SelectedStatus = "";
    }


   

    private async Task RowClick(DataGridRowMouseEventArgs<OrderDto> mouseClick)
    {
        await _grid!.ExpandRow(mouseClick.Data);
        SelectedOrders = _ordersDto.Where(o => o.Id == mouseClick.Data.Id).ToList();

        if (SelectedOrders.Count > 0)
        {
            if (SelectedOrders[0].Status == "Completed" || SelectedOrders[0].Status == "Cancelled")
            {
                _detailToInsert = new OrderDetailDto();
            }
            else
            {
                _detailToInsert = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task InsertDetailRow(int id)
    {
        _detailToInsert = new OrderDetailDto
        {
            OrderId = id,
            Status = "Order Opened"
        };

        await _gridDetail.InsertRow(_detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetailDto? orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            orderDetailMap = new OrderDetail();
            Mapper.Map(orderDetail, orderDetailMap);          
           
            var addedOrderDetail = await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetailMap);
            
                  
            await _gridDetail.Reload();
            await _grid.Reload();           
           
        }
    }


    
}
```

Orders:
[image]

Details:
[image]

**Edit 1:**

if I change the code like this; the grid is not collapsed and the new row is displayed but when I click another row and re-expand this row again, the newly added row disappears unless I reload the page.

```
private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetailDto? orderDetail)
{
    if (orderDetail != null)
    {
        orderDetailMap = new OrderDetail();
        Mapper.Map(orderDetail, orderDetailMap);
        
        var addedOrderDetail = await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetailMap);        
         
        Mapper.Map(addedOrderDetail, orderDetail);
        await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
        
       
    }
}
```